# Is there a way/programm to search for links on sites

Tags: search, website

Im looking for a program or way(Greasemonkey scripts included) to search for links in blog-type forum-type sites...

**Example**

Site : anydownloadsite.com
I would like to search for any links containing `(mysearch.site*)` contained in `anydownloadsite.com/sub1/` (and/or deeper level)
and if possible grab/list them

I tried IDM's Grabber but that doesn't grab links in pages,it grabs files...

Comment: There are programs that exist that have this type of functionality which implements a scripting-like language.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use wget, it depends on your needs.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857653/get-a-list-of-urls-from-a-site][1]

regards.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.